# Finding the number of non-blank columns in an Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I find the number of used columns in an Excel sheet using VBA?

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastRow
```

Using the above VBA I'm able to find the number of rows. But how do I find the number of columns in my given excel file?

Comment: @niko Its not clear whether you wanted the number of used columns (question title), or the position of the last used column (implied by your `row` code)?

Comment: @niko, a better method of finding the actual used portion of the sheet rather than the `xlUp` variants, or kludgy `UsedRange` is `Find`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283797/select-range-in-excel-vba/8283941#8283941

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your example code gets the row number of the last non-blank cell in the current column, and can be rewritten as follows:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastRow
```

It is then easy to see that the equivalent code to get the column number of the last non-blank cell in the current row is:

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox lastColumn
```

This may also be of use to you:

```
With Sheet1.UsedRange
    MsgBox .Rows.Count & " rows and " & .Columns.Count & " columns"
End With
```

but be aware that if column A and/or row 1 are blank, then this will not yield the same result as the other examples above. For more, read up on the `UsedRange` property.

Comment: Hi. I tried to use the code 
`Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastRow` 
but VBA says "Runtime error 424: Object required" at the second of those lines.

Now I am lost. Which function exactly does require an object and what did it get instead?

Comment: Do you actually have a sheet codenamed `Sheet1`? If not, then that's one thing that will cause that error.

Answer (score 8):

Jean-François Corbett's answer is perfect. To be exhaustive I would just like to add that *with some restrictons* you could also use `UsedRange.Columns.Count` or `UsedRange.Rows.Count`.
The problem is that UsedRange is not always updated when deleting rows/columns (at least until you reopen the workbook).

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the `UsedRange` bit as an afterthought, just to make the OP aware of this property and perhaps prompt some experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible you forgot a `sheet1` each time somewhere before the `columns.count`, or it will count the `activesheet` columns and not the `sheet1`'s.

Also, shouldn't it be xltoleft instead of xltoright? (Ok it is very late here, but I think I know my right from left) I checked it, you must write xltoleft.

```
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer:

```
numCols = objSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
```

[Documentation of the UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Result is shown in the following code as **column number** (8,9 etc.):

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox lastColumn
```

Result is shown in the following code as **letter** (H,I etc.):

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox Split(Sheet1.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1)
```