# Return a range from A1 to the true last used cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to select all the rows and columns in a spreadsheet. The macro needs to be dynamic, as the number of columns and rows tend to vary each time the macro would be called. It also needs to be able to account for blank rows and columns.

This subroutine accomplishes part of the process:

```
Sub FindLastCell()
Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Select
End Sub
```

It finds and selects the very last cell in a spreadsheet. Now that I've found the very last cell in the spreadsheet, how do I select cell A1 to the LastCell as a range?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to make these mods to the code

1. The sheet may be blank, so you should never use `Select` with `Find` as this will give an error if the Find returns nothing. Instead test that the range object `Is Not Nothing`
2. `Find` can search by row and by column. You need to determine **both** last row and column to determine the true last used cell
3. Once you have determined the true last cell use `Range` to set a range from the first cell (A1) to your cell determined with the two `Find` ranges

Pls see the code below

If the `Find` gets a value then it makes a range `rng3` from A1 to the last used cell identified by the two `Find`s.

[image]

```
Sub GetRange()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng3 = Range([a1], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
        MsgBox "Range is " & rng3.Address(0, 0)
        'if you need to actual select the range (which is rare in VBA)
        Application.Goto rng3 
    Else
        MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, that is a pretty kewl kewl way to perform the range function. I look the use of a procedure and use of iteration over recursion if only for the difference.

Answer (score 11):

Selecting A1 to the last cell used (including blanks in-between) in Column A is as simple as this:

```
Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

To select A1 to the last cell used in the entire sheet (regardless if it's used in column A or not):

```
Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Select
```

Comment: xlCellTypeLastCell will typically over estimate the last used cell position (from deleted data) unless you precede it with forcing a usedrange update, ie adding a line such as `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`. But I agree it is shorter than the Find I used which I adapted from a more specific need. cheers Dave.

Comment: Thanks for adding the note about refreshing usedrange! That's an important thing I should've mentioned.

Comment: What is wrong with my below selection?
MyRange = Range(myfile.Sheets("Summary").Range("A5:A") & myfile.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) - 2)

Comment: @aevanko, i tested the second line of code using `xlCellTypeLastCell` and it only selects column A.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to modify the code to select a range beginning at a specified cell, and ending at the last cell. On line 8, change the a1 to the cell you wish to start on.  In my case, I chose j28.

```
 Set rng3 = Range([j28], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
```

full code:

```
    Sub GetRange()
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim rng2 As Range
        Dim rng3 As Range
        Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng3 = Range([j28], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
            MsgBox "Range is " & rng3.Address(0, 0)
            'if you need to actual select the range (which is rare in VBA)
            Application.Goto rng3
        Else
            MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@brettdj pointed out the use of `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to clear the current used range. I would use the simple code below.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```