# Other method than Select in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select 
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row 
Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

I have read several places that using select is not recommended for copy pasting, and how can one do it without select?

Comment: Range(this).Value = Range(that).Value

Comment: Or iterate through the cells if you have more to copy

Comment: Using Loops... for loop for example

Comment: `Find` is also superior to `xlup` etc which doesn't handle edge cases (empty columns, full columns, or hidden cells). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283797/return-a-range-from-a1-to-the-true-last-used-cell/8283941#8283941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an exact analog to your code:

```
lastRow = x.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A65536").end(xlup).row
```

Added because of comment recommending better practices:

```
with x.worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row
end with
```

Comment: -1 for bad practice. What if we're using a 2007+ Version of Office and we have a spreadsheet with **hundreds of thousands** of rows? This would say row 65536 is the last row.

Comment: @RubberDuck, good point (1,048,576 to be exact).  Added 2nd option.

Comment: Good show old bean. Duly noted and vote reversed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `lastRow = x.worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

You need the first empty cell in the column, no the last one occupied