# identify the last used cell and paste below

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a total novice with VBA. I have the following code which does a matching exercise and then pastes the relevant values into col. B. my issue is each time the code is used the col will change how can I add this to the module so that it looks for the last cell used in row 1 and pastes the values below.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim myname As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrow1 = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow1
    myname = Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(i, "B").Value
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    lastrow2 = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(j, "A").Value = myname Then
            Sheets("Input Sheet").Activate
            Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(i, "c").Copy
            Sheets("Data").Activate
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, "B").Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next j
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the last used column in a given row - Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882143/find-out-the-last-used-column-in-a-given-row-excel-vba). This question does not have the answered accepted, but the answer is correct. There's also probably many more answers on SO about this if you search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your second `For j = 2 To lastrow2` with the `Match` function.

Also, there is no need to `Activate` the sheets back and fourth all the time, just use fully qualified `Range`s instead.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferData()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim myname As String
Dim MatchRng    As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
j = 2
With Sheets("Input Sheet")
    lastrow1 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the 2 lines bellow should be outisde the loop
    lastrow2 = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MatchRng = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastrow2)
    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        myname = .Range("B" & i).Value

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(myname, MatchRng, 0)) Then '<-- if successful Match
            Sheets("Data").Range("B" & j).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mark have you tried my code in the answer above ? any feedback ?

Comment: Shai, just looked at this. it works as expected but my problem is that each time the workbook is used a new date is added to row 1 on the Data sheet and this is where the new data needs to be pasted as it is the above code will only paste to ColB I need someway for the code to identify the correct location to paste.

Comment: @Mark this was not in your post above

Comment: I thought that's what I asked in the last part of my question, "my issue is each time the code is used the col will change how can I add this to the module so that it looks for the last cell used in row 1 and pastes the values below."