# Find last column & sort on last column

Tags: vba, excel

I need Excel to detect the last column I have and sort on that column. I have a macro that generates a new column every time it is used so I cannot use a constant.

```
Sub sortyness() 
Dim sortdata(A1 & ":", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)) As Range

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled").Sort.SortFields.Clear    
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled").Sort.SortFields.Add _    
    Key:=Range(Sorton), Sorton:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _    
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled").Sort    
    .SetRange Range(sortdata)    
    .Header = xlYes    
    .MatchCase = False    
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom    
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin    
    .Apply    
End With

End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the sheet:
[image: sheet]

I am having trouble with getting it to sort by the last column. Can I define the column by looking for the first cell in row 1 that has no data and then use that as a basis to sort? How should I modify my VBA?

Thank you.

I don't know how to edit this thing to get it to not appear as a duplicate, but it's obviously not a duplicate.  Mine is more concerned with running a macro on the last column than it is finding the last column.

Comment: Define "last".  Last column with data?  Last column in the worksheet?  Previous?

Comment: Last column with data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the last used column in a given row - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882143/find-out-the-last-used-column-in-a-given-row-excel-vba)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An vba sort operation actually requires much less code than you get from a recording.

```
Dim sortdata As Range, LastRow as long, LastColumn as long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled")
    LastRow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
    LastColumn = .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    with .range(.cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
         .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(.columns.count), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlyes
    end with
end with
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the second line here:

```
Dim sortdata(A1 & ":", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)) As Range
```

This is **not** how you assign range. If you want to assign a range, starting on `A1` and ending on `lastRow, lastColumn`, consider this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = 5
    Dim lastCol As Long: lastCol = 10

    Dim sortData As Range
    Set sortData = Range("A1:" & Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Address)

    Debug.Print sortData.Address

End Sub
```

In the above case the range is assigned to the `ActiveSheet`, which is not always what you may need. If you want to avoid assigning to the `ActiveSheet`, you should specify the worksheet as well:

```
With Worksheets("Compiled")
    Set sortData = .Range("A1:" & .Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Address)
End With
```

The two dots in the code above `.Range` and `.Cells` will make sure that you refer to the `Worksheets("Compiled")` and thus will save some problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that's where the majority of the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the "last" column with a single line of VBA:

```
    Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)._
        Column).Sort key1:=Columns(ActiveSheet._
        UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column)
```

...which is exactly the same as:

```
Sub SortLastColumn()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Columns(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column).Sort key1:=Columns(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column)
    End With
End Sub
```